# Mie Scattering for spheres with constant dipole moment

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering, classical-electrodynamics, dipole

I was wondering whether there exists a theory that describes Mie Scattering for spheres that have a constant dipole moment. Since there are theories that describe Mie scattering in the case of a charge, this might exist too?

Comment: It depends how big of a dipole field. What did you have in mind?